# how I can publish my web application and generate separate dlls?

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I mean when I publish my web application asp.net publisher generate one assembly why ? I like to have different assembly. is it possible ?

Comment: Generally you will have one assembly for each project in your solution.  If your solution only includes one project, then you will only have a single assembly.  If you want to have multiple assemblies, then architect your solution so that it spans multiple projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While publishing, Asp.net compiles all your code files into a single assembly and uploads it with other UI files i.e .aspx or .cshtml. It does so to make your application precomplied for faster performance. Every .net project has a single assembly. If you want to factor your assembly then make different projects according to your liking for getting different dlls.

For further information you visit this video link [Deploying A Web Application Using Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment Tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewaR-yFmi4w)

Answer (score 0):

If it is web application project you can have multiple class libraries and those will be complied in to several assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

That will require a good amount of work, so I hope that you have a good reason for it, but here is a guide to get you started:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;307467

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the menu Build > Publish > then on the Publish window click on settings on the left side, Expand "File Publish Options" > Check the precompile > Click on "Configure" then check "Do not merge" on the new window.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKfbC.png)